# преобразование js обьекта в c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc

есть такой код

```
@model ProfileViewModel
@{ViewBag.Title = "Profile/index.cshtml";}
<div>
    <nav>
        <div>
            @foreach (var folder in Model.Folders)
            {
                <a onclick="myFunction(@folder)">@folder.Name</a><br />
            }
        </div>
        <div id="demo"></div>
    </nav>
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction(data) {
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_dddd", data)
    }
</script>
```

передать методу Html.PartialAsync() атрибут data нельзя так как возникает ошибка:[image: ошибка]

вопрос: есть ли способ передать данные в функцию js и внутри функции передать их в функцию с#
.

P.s. учусь недавно поэтому могу высказываться не правильно.

Comment: ASP.NET или ASP.NET Core? Какая версия? Это Blazor  разметка или что? Какой тип страницы?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript документацию читать пробовали?

Comment: asp.net core, тип страницы: .cshtml

Comment: машина пока нет) почитаю подробнее про компоненты razor(файлы с расширением .razor, если сказал не правильно) спасибо за ответ(ง •_•)ง